# Proving the area function has an inverse

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

I am able to differentiate A at x using the FTC, but then I was wondering how one could show that A was one to one and prove that it has an inverse. If anybody could please help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $A'(x)=\frac {1-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sqrt {1-x^2}=\frac {1-2x-2-2x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac {-(1+x)^2-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\lt 0$  Since $A$ is continuous and monotonic, you can't have $A(x)=A(y)$ with $x \ne y$.  Given that it is one-to-one, it has an inverse over its range.

Comment: How do we know this function is one-one?

Comment: @Dick:  because the derivative doesn't change sign, the function is monotonic, in this case decreasing.  So for $x \lt y,\ \ A(x) \gt A(y)$ and it is one-to-one.